# Spring boot & mysql - connections closing

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jdbc

We have an application that needs to query 2 MySQL databases (one in each DC).  We have noticed that we are constantly closing and opening connections after we query the databases, this seems to be having a hit on performance.

```
HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.connectionImpl@xxxx (no operations allowed after connection closed.).  Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
HikariPool-1 - Closing connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.connectionImpl@xxxx (connection is dead)
...
HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.connectionImpl@xxxx (no operations allowed after connection closed.).  Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
HikariPool-1 - Closing connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.connectionImpl@xxxx (connection is dead)
...
(repeated per number of connections)
```

Followed by connections added again and we can see the pool stats confirming this.

```
HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.connectionImpl@xxxx
HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.connectionImpl@xxxx
HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.connectionImpl@xxxx
HikariPool-1 - pool stats (total=23, active=0, idle=23, waiting=0)
...
HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.connectionImpl@xxxx
HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.connectionImpl@xxxx
HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.connectionImpl@xxxx
HikariPool-1 - pool stats (total=26, active=0, idle=26, waiting=0)
...
HikariPool-1 - pool stats (total=30, active=0, idle=30, waiting=0)
...
etc
```

Has anyone seen this before?  I have tried changing the maxLifeTime value and idleTimeout with no effect.  I have also tried adding connectionTestQuery = SELECT 1, but the issue still happens.

My config:

application-dev.yml

```
spring:
   datasource1:
      driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      jdbcUrl: XXXX
      password: xxxx
      username: xxxx

      maximum-pool-size: 40
      test-while-idle: true
      test-on-borrow: false

      connection-timeout: 5000
      wait-timeout: 5000
   datasource2:
      driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      jdbcUrl: XXXX
      password: xxxx
      username: xxxx

      maximum-pool-size: 40
      test-while-idle: true
      test-on-borrow: false

      connection-timeout: 5000
      wait-timeout: 5000
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I moved from old Spring boot to 2.6.1 version and this problem started. Do you have same spring version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know why the connections where closing.  We took the vendors word on the database wait timeout, which they said was MySQL default (28800 seconds (8 hours)) ... it wasn't.

Running:

> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_%';

Showed the wait_timeout was set to 30 (30seoncds).

For us the fix was to increase the wait_timeout on the db by modifying the config and restarting the db.

We also started to use the hikari keepalivetime.

hikari:
keepaliveTime: 30000

Comment: Maybe you should look at the `OpenSessionInView` feature if you need to use some features it provides. But yes, that hikari keep alive setting could you reach the goal too.